# Example of a problem which can be solved faster using stack or queue

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue, stack

Only yesterday, I learned that there are data structures other than arrays. I understand the usefulness of sorted arrays: if you have to do many look-ups, it is **faster** to sort first and then do the look-ups.

However, I am very curious to see a problem which is solved **faster** by implementing and using stacks or queues, as opposed to play old arrays.

My online searches have yielded a lot of fun explanations about "plates" and "pancakes", but I haven't seen a concrete program or algorithm which makes use of stacks or queues to improve performance.

**Example Using Sorted Array**

Consider the problem of doing `m` look-ups in an array of `n` elements. If you just look directly, in the worst case you have to pay `n * m` operations. Now if you sort the array first (say, using Merge Sort), you have to pay at most `c * nlog(n)` (where `c` is some constant), and then for each of the `m` lookups you can do binary search and just pay `k * log(n)` (where `k` is another constant), so in total you pay `c * nlog(n) + m * k * log(n)`, which is much better than `m * n` if `n` is large and `m` is very large.

However

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392824/what-are-practical-applications-of-queues, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Applications_of_stacks

Comment: @Welbog Thanks for the link. I see examples such as the use of the "undo" button; the most recent changes are stored at the top of the stack. However, I don't see how this is faster than storing the changes sequentially in an array, and accessing them by index (if the user clicks undo 3 times, go 3 memory locations back from the end of the array).

Comment: In all the examples I read, they are using stacks/queues **conceptually**. But I don't see why it's **faster** to use them in practice.  I know that speed isn't the only thing we care about, but I am asking if there is an example where the speed **is** improved by implementing and using stacks/queues.

Comment: Arrays do not have O(1) insertion or O(1) deletion. Most canonical examples of applying stacks and queues make use of both to run efficiently for large inputs, and will therefore be much faster. A queue implemented with an array will have O(n) worst-case insertion or deletion time, or will eventually run out of space. A stack implemented thus will have similar limitations. Linked-list-based stacks and queues will have constant-time insert and delete operations. Also note that stacks and queues are abstract and can be implemented multiple ways. You're more comparing arrays to linked lists.

Comment: A stack or a queue can be implemented using an array, with pushes and pops taking constant time. Hence, *nothing* can be done faster with a stack or a queue.

Comment: @Welbog How is insertion into a linked list `O(1)`? If I want to insert a new node N in the ith position of the linked list, don't I have to start from the head and go from node to node, which is `O(n)` time?

Comment: You're describing find (O(n)) followed by insert (O(1)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are a basic data structure. In fact, computer memory is an array, and since we can use computer memory to solve all kinds of problems, we can always say we solved them using an array.

Queues and stacks are higher level structures, with specific (also constraining) rules, sometimes implemented directly with arrays, with just some logic to maintain one or two indexes/pointers.

So in essence: what you can solve with a queue or a stack, you can also solve (with the same time complexity) with an array.

Now, you also mentioned *sorted* arrays. They are indeed useful. However, when the algorithm must regularly add new values to it, and keep the array sorted, it can become inefficient. That leads to some other data structure you might look into: a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

Just like stacks and queues, so also binary heaps can be "just" arrays, and binary heaps typically *are* implemented as arrays. But a heap allows to extract the minimum value from it with a O(logn) time complexity without the need to apply a O(nlogn) sorting algorithm on it first. An array can be turned into a heap in linear time. It also allows to insert a new value into it in O(logn) time. A sorted array cannot offer that, since on average it involves shifting O(n) values to make room for the new value.

A heap can serve as implementation of a priority queue. For example, heaps are useful for efficient [best-first searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) in weighted graphs.

In conclusion: making the comparison with arrays is not really telling us anything: stacks, queues, sorted arrays, and heaps are (can be) arrays. What really is decisive is: what is the logic used to perform basic operations on the data, such as build, insert, delete, and find? When we talk of data structures, we silently *include* that basic logic in their meaning: stacks, queues, and heaps are (can be) arrays with certain rules and smart operations.